# Round floats down in Python to keep one non-zero decimal only

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, rounding

I have a Python list only filled with floats:

```
list_num = [0.41, 0.093, 0.002, 1.59, 0.0079, 0.080, 0.375]
```

I need to round this list down to get:

```
list_num_rounded = [0.4, 0.09, 0.002, 1.5, 0.007, 0.08, 0.3]
```

**Problem:**
Rounding 1.59 to 1.5 is easy to do. However, my problem is with floats that are less than 1.

**Question:**
Basically, I need to round all floats down so that: if the float is < 1, then the rounded version only contains one non-zero number. Is there a way to do this in Python 2.7?

**Attempt:**
Here is what I have tried:

```
list_num_rounded = []
for elem in list_num:
    if elem > 0.01 and elem < 0.1:
        list_num_rounded.append(round(elem,2))
    if elem > 0.001 and elem < 0.01:
        list_num_rounded.append(round(elem,3))
    elif elem > 0.1:
        list_num_rounded.append(round(elem,1))
```

However, this gives:

```
[0.4, 0.09, 0.002, 1.6, 0.008, 0.08, 0.4]
```

It is rounding 1.59, 0.79 and 0.375 up, but I need a way to only round down. Is there a way to do this?

The list will not contain negative floats. Only positive floats will be present.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use logarithms to work out how many leading zeroes there are, then you need a way to round down. One way is to use floor like so:

```
import math

list_num = [0.41, 0.093, 0.002, 1.59, 0.0079, 0.080, 0.375, 0, 10.1, -0.061]


def myround(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    sgn = -1 if n < 0 else 1
    scale = int(-math.floor(math.log10(abs(n))))
    if scale <= 0:
        scale = 1
    factor = 10**scale
    return sgn*math.floor(abs(n)*factor)/factor


print [myround(x) for x in list_num]
```

Output:

```
[0.4, 0.09, 0.002, 1.5, 0.007, 0.08, 0.3]
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle negative numbers and numbers greater than 1, this rounds negative numbers up and numbers greater than 1 to 1dp.

Comment: I updated the original post. There will not be negative floats in the list. Regarding numbers >1, sorry I think I am not understanding. You already have a number >1 in your example ---> 1.59. Your solution works for this  - correct?

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out for numbers >1. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I saw 1.59 in the example data. But, for example, what does 1059.56 round to? I assumed it would round down to 1 decimal place (so 1059.5).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification. I can just add an `if` statement to handle that case separately. I am going to accept this answer since your function appears to work just fine for all other cases listed in the question in the original post. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Given that all of the floats are positive you could convert them to strings and use slicing like this.

```
def round(num):
    working = str(num-int(num))
    for i, e in enumerate(working[2:]):
        if e != '0':
            return int(num) + float(working[:i+3])

list_num = [0.41, 0.093, 0.002, 1.59, 0.0079, 0.080, 0.375]
new_list = [round(x) for x in list_num]
print new_list
```

prints

```
[0.4, 0.09, 0.002, 1.5, 0.007, 0.08, 0.3]
```

If there could be floats in the list with no non-zero values after the decimal you will need to add a simple check to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

We solve the problem by identifying the number of zeros until the first decimal in the floating part, and then round using this value.

```
def round_float(num):
    if not num:
        return num
    current_num = abs(num) * 10
    round_value = 1

    while not (current_num//1):
        current_num *= 10
        round_value +=1

    return round(num, round_value)
```

Comment: Please comment your code and share what you've done to make it work and why your answer is valid

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester you're harsh, imo this is the most elegant solution  here & the code speaks for itself.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting your float numbers to scientific notation can help; then converting back to float types should achieve what you want. Try something like:

```
eval("%.0e" % (.03))
eval("%.0e" % (.034))
eval("%.0e" % (.0034))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure I follow. I tried `print eval("%.0e" % (.375))` and I got 0.4. Do you have an example?

Comment: This doesn't quite work for numbers larger than 1. If you did this for example: `[eval("%.0e"%(element)) for element in list_num]`, 1.59 becomes 2.0.

Comment: You are right; it will round the numbers to one digit but not round them down. You could try something like `x="%.1e" % (.375); eval( x[:2]+"0"+x[3:])` if you want to try with the same idea.